# Clustered index

Tags: sql-server, indexing

Is this true that Update SQL Query is slow because of Clustered index??????

Comment: This question needs to be clarified, slow compared to what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define slow, ofcourse the clustered index will always be slower than a non-clustered index...

Answer (score 6):

You would be better off saying 'slower' rather than 'slow'. When data is written to a clustered index, and it doesn't go at the very end of the table, data needs to be joggled around in order to fit it in, in the same way that adding a CD into a big stack of alphabetised CD is a lot slower than just sticking it on the top.

Comment: then what should i do...in this case ???
Remove the clustered index from id  and then update the data...

Comment: NO - pick the *RIGHT* clustered index (small, stable, never-changing, ever-increasing, *NOT* a GUID) and be happy with it!

Comment: I HAVE id COLUMN WHICH IS HAVE PRIMARY KEY 

SO ITS A CLUSERED INDEX.

Comment: Not necessarily - a primary key need not be a clustered index (though it can be).

Comment: what kind of value is the id column?

if it is an auto-incrementing integer key then you shouldn't be updating the id value (you can update the other columns fine), in which case the row will not change.

if it is a natural key, it either doesn't change very often (i mean seriously, how often do people change their social security number?) in which case you don't need to worry about it as the slow updates are infrequent, or the updates are frequent, in which case drop the clustered index, and create a new auto-incrementing integer and cluster on that. And do lookups on that.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have any clustered indexes at all, then what you have is termed a "heap". You also have a heap of trouble, since the order of the data in your table is random - and selecting data from the table will be *slow*. That may be OK if you're doing many more `INSERT`s than you are `SELECT`s, but usually that's not the case.

Whether the clustered index makes `INSERT`s slower or not depends on:

- The fill factor of the table (i.e. whether there are enough gaps in the data to allow new data to be inserted without moving everything around).
- What columns are chosen as the cluster key.

If you're using an identity column as the cluster key, then you may find that insert performance is perfectly fine, since new entries are always being added on the end. The same may apply to a datetime column if using the current date (which of course also keeps increasing).

You need to keep the size of the cluster key small, since that's the index into the data that's stored in every other index. For example, if your cluster key consists of 3 ints and a datetime, then each entry in all your other indexes will include all that data in addition to whatever it was that you tried to index. For this reason, an identity column is actually a pretty good choice of cluster key since it's nice & small.

The perfect cluster key in any situation can only be chosen with a good deal of thought and a lot of testing (with realistically large data sets). Having a good cluster key can make a **huge** difference to `SELECT` performance - which normally outweighs any degradation in `INSERT` performance.

Comment: Selecting data from a heap isn't slower or faster because the rows are added "randomly". A clustered index is only order on one set of columns... for every other set of columns the rows are essentially random. If that one case is how you're trying to access the data and you're doing a range scan, then you'll get some efficiency.

Comment: It's like in SQL Server land everything is accessed by PK (i.e. clustered index). Secondary indexes are rarely discussed

Answer (score 1):

Insertion and updates are *slower* because of clustered indexes (particularly on huge tables) - but selects are way faster.

Making the index **non-clustered** usually improves inserts and updates performance retaining selection performance (selects are often less *performant* with a non-clustered index compared with a clustered index but something's gotta give).

Answer (score 1):

A clustered index dictates how a table is physically stored on disk, and so updating a table with a clustered index *may* require that significant parts of the table be moved to make space for the new record, and that's slow.

You can mitigate the problem by setting an appropriate fillfactor for your indexes.  It's not quite so bad that you have to re-jigger the whole table when you add a record to the middle; it's usually just a few pages.  Fillfactor determines how much of each page is filled before creating a new page, and how much to leave as wiggle room for new insertions.  A lower fillfactor on an index will leave more space for new records and therefore give faster insert times on average, at the cost of more disk space and more pages and therefore slower reads.  But if you're doing a lot more updating than reading it may be worth it.